# ICS 4 text appearance configuration

Tags: android

I have a textView with text="Address". In Android ICS, i sometimes see it in my screen like

```
Addres

s
```

and not in the same line

```
Address
```

How can i fix it?There is no problem with the available space in the screen..Thanks

This is the xml for the textView:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text_title"
android:textColor="#780000"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="26px"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
/>
```

Comment: is there any way to tell it that i want always to have the textView in the same line??

Comment: i have used android:lines="1" but its not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//use always "sp" for font and rest as "dp"

//here you are using wrap content then position is not enough to display you text content

try `android:layout_weight="1"` or change you android:layout_width="fill_parent"

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text_title"
android:textColor="#780000"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
/>
```

give 16sp default is 14sp.

if your running ICS i.e xhdpi then it will automatically adjust to

```
16×240÷160 = 24 //hdpi
 16×320÷160 =32 //for xhdpi
```

Comment: Yes, i fixed it before your answer!Anyway thanks for your time,that was a silly question!:)